# calculus 3 critical,max, min and saddle points

Tags: calculus

I want to find critical point of this function $$z=x^3+3x^2+y^3+3y^2+27$$ 
$$\nabla f_1 (x,y,z) = 3x^2+6x$$
$$\nabla f_2 (x,y,z) = 3y^2+6y$$
$$\nabla f_3 (x,y,z) = -1$$
I am getting $x = 0$ or $x = -2$ and $y = 0$ or $y = -2$, but I am not sure if I am doing it right, can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: We don't know what you have been doing. Wouldn't it be better if you included your work in the question so that your mistake can be pointed out? Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question for easy readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, the set of critical points is $\{x;y\} = \{-2/ 0; -2/0\}$ (as you said) for a total of four critical points.
Your gradient is fine but you didn't give much detail, make sure your teacher understands your steps a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I wrote all the steps, to get that points. Thanks